# I just got a new Android phone and I'm wondering how google got all my old phone numbers

Tags: contacts, sim-card

I finally upgraded from an incredibly old and aging blackberry to a new Galaxy S5.  I like the phone, but the amount of information google is trying to squeeze out of me is feeling incredibly invasive.

The phone came with a new SIM card that I put in it and when I turned it on and looked at my contact list, I was very surprised that it had somehow obtained every phone number on my blackberry.  I'm wondering how Google managed to get all my old phone numbers.  I want to reiterate, this is my first android phone ever and before that I was just on a blackberry.  Also, the names were specifically what I entered in my blackberry word for word.  It even included numbers like #AUTO and things like that.

I honestly don't know if these numbers were somehow in my google contacts previously as I rarely checked that screen, but they're sure as hell there now.  Additionally, I never once installed a google app on my blackberry at any point in the years and years I've owned it.

Could anyone shed light on how this happened?  Did it happen when my phone carrier activated my new SIM somehow?

Thanks, I'm not really technically versed in the world of phones but this has me really freaked out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think [BIS](http://www.blackberry.com/newsletters/connection/ce/i910/wirelessly_sync.shtml) was automatically syncing your Blackberry contacts to Google server. When you added Google account to your Android, it automatically imported all your contacts from Google server.

Comment: Aha!  I booted up my old blackberry to check and after some menu diving I found that it was indeed syncing the contact list to my email account!

Thanks so much, I was freaking out a bit lol.  I guess it never clicked in my mind that setting up the email client with a gmail account would link other things on the phone. Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome @Weaver :)